# Manipulate string based on characters in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on some data manipulations with time intervals, and have two time formats in the pandas dataframe. Every first occurrence of the time interval is duplicated (1:221:22 in the example below), and the second occurrence is in quotations and preceded by two commas. How can I manipulate the data as effectively as possible?

From example data:

```
    obs1, 1:221:22,
    obs2, ",,1:22"
```

To:

```
    obs1, 1:22,
    obs2, 1:22
```

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes, I am using pandas, included in question

Comment: This are the only types of values that you have on your column? So every value will be or duplicated or starting with ",,"

Comment: Yes, all data is formatted as the example

Comment: Please be more specific about what the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need one filter to separate how to threat the columns.

```
filter_commas = (df[comma_column].str.startswith(",,"))
```

Then you have to threat based on your data.

```
#First removing all the commas at start
df.loc[filter_commas,column_name] = df.loc[filter_commas, column_name].str.replace(",","")
```

Then you have to split the data for the ones that aren't

```
#Splitting the rest of rows based in half of the row length
df.loc[~filter_commas,column_name] = df.loc[~filter_commas,column_name].apply(lambda row_val: row_val[:len(row_val)/2])
```

The code maybe wrong but this should put you in the right track

Comment: Thanks, solved it by using:

`filter_commas = (df[comma_column].str.startswith(",,"))`
`df.loc[filter_commas,column_name] = df.loc[filter_commas, column_name].str.replace("^,+", "", regex=True)`
`df.loc[~filter_commas,column_name] = df.loc[~filter_commas,column_name].apply(lambda row_val: row_val[:len(row_val) // 2])`

Comment: good, I just edited correcting the index. Heads up, the replace without the regexp pattern will be faster, o and if it's right  please assign as the answer.